# How to call a python script from swi-prolog terminal

Tags: python, prolog, swi-prolog

Swi-prolog provides an in-built "shell" predicate to interact with operating system but the documentation is poor.

For a Windows platform, I want to execute something like this:

`shell('cmd.exe python file_name.py')`

This hangs the terminal!

But if I use: `shell('cmd.exe ipconfig')`
This gives a true and hence I suppose it is working.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `process_create/3` inside a `setup_call_cleanup/3`

I have not tried this in windows  just linux but I think it would be similar:
(I also show how to call jars)

```
run_jar(Jar,Option,Lines):-
    setup_call_cleanup(
    process_create(path(java),['-jar',Jar,Option],[stdout(pipe(Out))]),
    read_lines(Out,Lines),
    close(Out)).

run_python(Script,Option,Lines):-
    setup_call_cleanup(
    process_create(path(python),[Script,Option],[stdout(pipe(Out))]),
    read_lines(Out,Lines),
    close(Out)).

read_lines(Out, Lines) :-
        read_line_to_codes(Out, Line1),
        read_lines(Line1, Out, Lines).

read_lines(end_of_file, _, []) :- !.
read_lines(Codes, Out, [Line|Lines]) :-
        atom_codes(Line, Codes),
        read_line_to_codes(Out, Line2),
        read_lines(Line2, Out, Lines).
```

Comment: With SWI-Prolog 7 and later, your `read_lines` can be as simple as `read_string(Stream, _, Str_input), split_string(Str_input, "\n", "\n", Str_lines)`. You can add `maplist(atom_string, Lines, Str_lines)` if you want each line as an atom.